# Confusion on the proof of the Divergence Test

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

There is a step in the proof of the divergence test that I'm not understanding, where the difference of two partial sums equals the the sequence of terms. So I'm going to write out the whole proof and then point to the step that has me confused to help anyone that can tell me where I'm going wrong. So let's assume that the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ converges, and we want to prove that this then implies that the sequence of terms converges to zero, $a_n\rightarrow0$. Since $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ converges, then the sequence of partial sums $(s_n)$ converges, thus Cauchy. By definition then, for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $N$ such that for all $n,m > N$ we have
$|s_n - s_m| < \epsilon$. WLOG let $n\ge m$, then unwinding the definition of partial sums we get $|\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k - \sum_{k=1}^{m}a_k| < \epsilon$ which is equivalent to $|\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}a_k| < \epsilon$. Since this is true for all $n,m > N$ then this is true in particular for $m = n - 1$ thus we get $|\sum_{k=n}^{n}a_k| < \epsilon$ then $|a_n|<\epsilon$ and finally to the desired $|a_n - 0|<\epsilon$. The step that has me confused is the one where we go from $|\sum_{k=n}^{n}a_k| < \epsilon$ to $|a_n|<\epsilon$. How does the difference of two partial sums, n and m here, equal an infinite sequence of terms? I get how we get here symbolically but it doesn't make sense. Where am I going wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Where is the "infinite sequence of terms" you mention?

Answer (score 2):

I think you just have a notational confusion: the notation $\sum_{k = n}^n a_k$ literally just means the sum of all $a_k$ where $k$ starts at $n$ and increasing by $1$ until $k$ gets to $n$. That is, only a single term, $a_n$ itself! So $\sum_{k = n}^n a_k$ is a sum of one term only, and is equal to $a_n$ *on the nose*. Thus we can go from from $\lvert\sum_{k=n}^{n}a_k \rvert < \epsilon$ to $\lvert a_n\rvert<\epsilon$ because they mean the same thing!

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhh. That makes sense, so this $a_n$ just represents all the terms n > N (the one we assumed existed by the Cauchy definition) such that $|a_n| < \epsilon$ but this $a_n$ isn't a sequence just the individual terms for n > N? I got confused since to prove sequence convergence we have to prove that there are infinitely many terms past a certain point that are within epsilon> 0 of the supposed limit.